# unset export-ignore for selected files in git

Tags: git

I am trying to use .gitattributes to selectively create an an archive file with only the files I want in it..

I want `git archive` to ignore everything except for the things i want..

so I've trued to use the -export-ignore attribute
ie .gitattributes

```
* export-ignore
/somedir/orfile -export-ignore
```

to produce an archive with only `/somedir/orfile` in it.

I just haven't been able to get it to work for me.

I feel like it should work in the same was as .gitattributes supports text/-text

I'm using git version 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `export-ignore` excludes files from exporting. So if you only want to ignore everything except `/somedir/orfile`, you have to mention all other directories.

Say, you have directories a, b and c. To only export a:

```
b/ -export-ignore
c/ -export-ignore
```